# Ruby OpenStruct

Tags: ruby

I'm working with an array of OpenStruct objects which looks like this:

```
a=[<OpenStruct name="test1", x="6", id="1">,<OpenStruct name="test2", x="5", id="2"><OpenStruct name="test1", x="8", id="3">...]
```

I would like to group the OpenStruct objects having the same name, something like this:

```
a=[<OpenStruct name="test1",x=["6","8"], id=["1","3"]>,<OpenStruct name="test2", x="5", id="2">]
```

How can I do that?

Comment: did you look at `groupBy`? It seems useful :-)

Comment: @JanDvorak `groupBy` groups the elements, not their attributes.

Answer (score 1):

You could use group_by and map methods. I think the code is self explanatory.

```
a = [
  OpenStruct.new(name: "test1", x: "6", id: "1"),
  OpenStruct.new(name: "test2", x: "5", id: "2"),
  OpenStruct.new(name: "test1", x: "8", id: "3")
]

a.group_by(&:name).map do |name, as|
  OpenStruct.new(
    name: name,
    x: as.map(&:x),
    id: as.map(&:id)
  )
end
# => [#<OpenStruct name="test1", x=["6", "8"], id=["1", "3"]>, #<OpenStruct name="test2", x=["5"], id=["2"]>]
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
a = [
  OpenStruct.new(name: "test1", x: "6", id: "1"),
  OpenStruct.new(name: "test2", x: "5", id: "2"),
  OpenStruct.new(name: "test1", x: "8", id: "3")
]

a.each_with_object({}) { |o, h|
  h[o.name] ||= OpenStruct.new(name: o.name, x: [], id: [])
  h[o.name][:x] << o.x
  h[o.name][:id] << o.id
}.values
#=> [#<OpenStruct name="test1", x=["6", "8"], id=["1", "3"]>, #<OpenStruct name="test2", x=["5"], id=["2"]>]
```

Note that the `x` and `id` attributes for `test2` are also converted to arrays. This is usually preferred.

It might be good idea to rename the attributes to indicate an array, i.e. `ids` instead of `id`.